# No end point defined while access wcf on lan

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-endpoint

This is my app.config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="HelloWorldService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="HelloWorldService.HelloWorld">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HelloWorldService.IHelloWorld">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/HelloWorldService/HelloWorld/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <applicationSettings>
    <HelloWorldService.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="conString" serializeAs="String">
        <value>Data Source=192.168.1.1,1433;Initial Catalog=Cock;Integrated Security = false;user=ok;password=123;</value>
      </setting>
    </HelloWorldService.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Following is the error that's am getting while accessing wcf service.

> There was no endpoint listening at http://*:8080/HelloWorld.svc that
>   could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have hosted service on 8733 port.

Try accessing service with below url.

```
http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/HelloWorldService/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.svc
```

or

```
http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/HelloWorldService/HelloWorld.svc
```

Comment: basically i am trying to access that service on an other machine

Comment: so use ip-address instead of localhost